# Berkeley Database - Duplicate Entries Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, database, segmentation-fault, berkeley-db

So I'm currently working on a Berkeley database through C, and I ran into a little problem concerning allowing duplicate data. If I don't allow duplicate entries through DB->set_flags and I iterate through the items in the database with a cursor, everything works just fine. The moment I add the DB->set_flags line in my program, and change nothing else, I get a segmentation fault and I don't know how to fix it, considering it works just fine without duplicate entries. The code is as follows:

```
DB *dates_db;
db_create(&dates_db, NULL, 0);
dates_db->set_flags(dates_db, DB_DUP);
dates_db->open(dates_db, NULL, "da.idx", NULL, DB_BTREE, 0, 0664);

DBT key, data;
memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key)); 
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

DBC *DBpointer;
dates_db->cursor(dates_db, NULL, &DBpointer, 0);

while(DBpointer->c_get(DBpointer, &key, &data, DB_NEXT) != DB_NOTFOUND)
{
    printf("The key is: %s\nThe data is: %s\n", (char *)key.data, (char *)data.data);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I need to add? I've checked the sourceforge page that has all the information about Berkeley DB and as far as I know, I only need to add the DB->set_flags line to allow duplicate entries, but could there be something I've missed?

Comment: For a start, you should _always_ check return values when a function can fail. That probably not your immediate problem, but it's still good practice.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to obtain the return value of the DBpointer->c_get call, but it's the reason I'm getting the segmentation fault so I can't even find out what it is. :S Even if I take it out of the while loop and call it once, I still get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you should always check return values when a function can fail.

Specifically, `db_create`, `set_flags`, `open`, `cursor` *all* return an error indication.

If, as you seem to indicate in a comment, it's the `c_get` causing the SIGSEGV, you may want to ensure that the cursor was indeed created properly.

Changing:

```
DBC *DBpointer;
dates_db->cursor(dates_db, NULL, &DBpointer, 0);
```

to:

```
DBC *DBpointer = (DBC*)0xdeadbeef;
int rc = dates_db->cursor(dates_db, NULL, &DBpointer, 0);
printf ("DEBUG: %d %p\n", rc, DBpointer);
fflush (stdio); // and possibly also: fsync (fileno (stdio));
```

would be a good start.

Better would be to go all the way and use something like:

```
#define CHKERR(x) if(rc!=0){printf("%s err=%d\n",x,rc);fflush(stdout);exit(1);}
int rc;
DB *dates_db;

rc = db_create(&dates_db, NULL, 0);
CHKERR("create");

rc = dates_db->set_flags(dates_db, DB_DUP);
CHKERR("set_flags");

rc = dates_db->open(dates_db, NULL, "da.idx", NULL, DB_BTREE, 0, 0664);
CHKERR("open");

DBT key, data;
memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key)); 
memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));

DBC *DBpointer;
rc = dates_db->cursor(dates_db, NULL, &DBpointer, 0);
CHKERR("cursor");

while((rc = DBpointer->c_get(DBpointer, &key, &data, DB_NEXT)) != DB_NOTFOUND)
{
    CHKERR("c_get");
    printf("The key is: %s\nThe data is: %s\n", (char *)key.data, (char *)data.data);
}
```

---

Based on a further comment that you're getting error 22 on the open call, that's `EINVAL` (on my system at least) which means one of your parameters is incorrect.

Based on web searches, there appear to be a few variations on the `open` call, ranging between five and seven arguments. Some [Oracle BDB doco](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/BDB_Prog_Reference.pdf) states that it takes *five* argument (no database pointer and not transaction pointer) but the sample code in the same document (and [other Oracle doco](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/BDB-C_APIReference.pdf)) has your seven-argument form.

It may be worthwhile looking into your BDB header files to see which one you should be using.

Comment: I think it may be the lack of sleep getting to me, but I deleted my comment because I saw the last part of your answer had the same exact info as my comment did and I thought I didn't read your answer, but I just realized that you edited your answer in response to my comment. But in any case, I tried both adding the name in quotations (as I've done in the incorrect field) and through fopen'ing the file and then passing the pointer, but each time, I can't even compile because I'm passing argument 2 from incompatible argument type. How do I fix this? Why did it work before but not now?

Comment: @Gabe, go grab the prototype line from your `db.h` header file. That will tell you the correct form to use.

Comment: Ok, I am most definitely using the seven argument format through me removing arguments from the call (and the compiler complaining that not enough arguments were entered) and through what little information we were given:
open(student_db, NULL, “studentsdb”, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664) where each field corresponds, respectively, to:
/* pointer to db structure */
/* transaction pointer */
/* the name of the database on disk */
/* logical database name (optional) */
/* database access method */
/* database access method */
/* unix file mode */

Comment: And I'm not linux savvy enough to even find the header file and look through it, but it shouldn't matter as I've even tried the five argument model and the compiler complained that several arguments were of the incorrect type and that not enough arguments were passed.